# Почему не выполняется синхронная анимация?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Необходимо после запуска анимации окружности запустить через одну секунду анимацию прямоугольника.

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke='black' width='500' height='500' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
  <circle r="30" cx="30" cy="50%" fill='orange' id='a' stroke='none' />
  <rect id='b' x="20" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="#0099cc"></rect>

  <animate xlink:href='#a' attributeName='cx'  from='10' to='470' dur='1s' begin='click' fill='freeze' d='circ-anim'  /> 
  <animate xlink:href='#b' attributeName='x' from='0' to='470' dur='3s' begin='circ-anim.begin + 1s' fill='freeze'/>
</svg>
```

Сейчас запускается только одна анимация окружности.

В чём может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В условиях запуска анимации - `begin`, рекомендуется явно указывать `id` элемента svg, в данном примере  окружности или прямоугольника. Можно также указать `id` всего холста SVG

`begin="a.click"` или `begin="b.click"` или `begin="svg1.click"`

Опечатка: d="circ-anim" правильно id="circ-anim"

**Рекомендация**: избегать знака минус в присвоении имен `id` анимации, так как Firefox это воспринимает не как имя уникального Идентифика́тора, а как знак минус.

правильно для кроссбраузерности - `id="circ_anim"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke='black' width='500' height='500' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
  <circle id='a' r="30" cx="30" cy="50%" fill='orange'  stroke='none' />
  <rect id='b' x="20" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="#0099cc"></rect>

  <animate
    id="circ_anim"
 xlink:href='#a'
 attributeName='cx'
 from='10'
 to='470'
 dur='1s'
 begin='svg1.click'
 fill='freeze'   /> 
  <animate
    xlink:href='#b'
 attributeName='x'
 from='20'
 to='470'
 dur='3s'
 begin='circ_anim.begin + 1s'
 fill='freeze'/>
</svg>
```

В Chrome такого ограничения не существует.

В качестве бонуса можно создать зацикливание анимаций, то есть после завершения второй анимации (прямоугольника ) начнется первая анимация (окружности )

Для этого пишется условие `begin="svg1.click;rect_anim.end"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke='black' width='500' height='500' style='border: 1px solid black;'>
  <circle id='a' r="30" cx="30" cy="50%" fill='orange'  stroke='none' />
  <rect id='b' x="20" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="#0099cc"></rect>

  <animate 
    id="circ_anim"
 xlink:href='#a'
 attributeName='cx'
 values="30;470;30"
 dur='1s'
 begin='svg1.click;rect_anim.end'
 fill='freeze'   /> 
  <animate id="rect_anim"
    xlink:href='#b'
 attributeName='x'
 values="20;470;20"
 dur='2s'
 begin='circ_anim.end + 1s'
 fill='freeze'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: желтый круг во время анимации справа обрезается и как можно исправить ?

Comment: @Leks путь сделать короче